# How to deal with an aliased predictor in a generalized linear model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sas

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vc6yv2mqfm2xots/AAAc-yCyrUR9QBnohNjttFxVa?dl=0

Using the attached data, I am working on the effects of poverty on farmers' adaptive capacities  (N=1211). Multivariate analysis is used to isolate interactions between different determinants. My dependent variable (nb_success) measures the number of changes in agricultural practises. The variable is bounded (0-9) and a binomial distribution with a logit link function fits the data well.

However, I have an issue with the poverty variable (DEP_TOT). When running the regression with other determinants, the variable has zero degrees of freedom and SAS displays a value of zero for both the parameter estimate and its standard error

I used the following SAS command where nb_trials is =5:

```
proc genmod data= data1 ; 
model  nb_success/nb_trials = 
m002 Dist_marche SS_nb_s SS_part_travaux_agri SS_CeRPA 
m104 com 
dep_tot m15 i705 PART_ASSO part_ceremonies
i102 i101 Educ 
p_sp p_temp/ dist=bin link=logit  ;run;
```

My understanding is that SAS finds (DEP_TOT) to be linearly dependent, or aliased, with columns corresponding to parameters preceding it in the model. However, when I run the model with this variable as a unique predicator, the problem persists. Another variable (number of childrens in the households) is correlated with this variable. When I drop the number of children, the issue remains. The model works well when DEP_TOT is log  transformed or stratified in deciles and even quartiles.

Any idea where the issue may lies?
Would log-transform an independent variable in a GLM be an issue?

Comment: Is it possible to disclose your data?

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the data. Does the predictor actually take on distinct values?

Comment: Thanks, I attached a link with the problematic predictor

Comment: Would you be so kind as to write what you regress on what? I am not sure I understand which/what model, you are trying to estimate from your question.

Answer (score 0):

NB_trials is always 5, you can't use that in a regression where you also include a intercept. I have no (computational at least) problems with regressing: nb_succes on a constant and dep_tot

Comment: Thanks. The binomial GLM i m run is regressing nb.succes / nb trials. If we do not include the nb of trials and only regress nb success, would it still be a valid GLM binomial model?

Comment: @FrédéricK. post your code in the question as well

Comment: @Repmat. Which code did you use? dropping the constant nb_trials from the command results in a SAS error.

Comment: I am not sure we are running the same model then. Would be so kind as to update your question, with a mathematical stated model?

Comment: One thing I do not fully understand is whether it is valid or not to use an independent log varible in a GLM with logit link?

Comment: @Repmat. I guess you can run the same model using different commands in Sas. I may mot use the most relevant